# react truffle box calling solidity with addresses issues

Tags: react, truffle-box

[Repository](https://github.com/shaddow1201/CredentialVerify)

I've tested the solidity side and things seem to work appropriately.  However my hooking up the react box is running into a few problems.

I seem to have varying problems related to addressing and calling functions.

[App.js](https://github.com/shaddow1201/CredentialVerify/blob/master/src/App.js)

in the instantiateContracts function and in the Check Function.

the uncommented out 'return' lines are the ones that WORK, the uncommented returns DO work.

Also on the attempt to push a credentialOrg (button) i get an Error: invalid address on all attempts.

I expect I'm missing something basic.

this may be a clue: this is the last [result](https://www.screencast.com/t/bElIqe9G)  and can't retrieve the values via result.c[0], etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was related to how i was populating the accounts, in the 2_deploy_contracts.js and I needed double quotes around them.  Once this was done the variance went away.